# How to test a simply if-statement in a function with JASMINE

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

Could anybody help me to test this simple function please?

I have to write a test in `JASMINE` for the `function check_if_mobile_width()`.

After endless searching I tried with 'Jasmine Spy' but don't understand how it exactly works...

I always get this error:

```
Expected spy addClass to have been called. (1)
```

Function:

```
function check_if_mobile_width() {
if ($(window).width() < 979) {
    $.root_.addClass('mobile-view-activated')
} else if ($.root_.hasClass('mobile-view-activated')) {
    $.root_.removeClass('mobile-view-activated');
}}
```

TEST:

```
describe("desktop or mobile -- check_if_mobile_width()", function(){
it("should return the kind of the device", function(){

    check_if_mobile_width();
    spyOn($.root_, "addClass"); 
    spyOn($.root_, "removeClass");

    if($(window).width() < 979)
        expect($.root_.addClass).toHaveBeenCalled();

    else 
        expect($.root_.removeClass).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should add a spy _before_ calling the function?...

Comment: Also, you don't need to have an if-clause in your test.

Comment: Thank you very much!  --- I added the spy before calling the function and removed the if-clause --> and now it's working! :-)